# Getting the path in A star algorithm by backtracking

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star

i wanted to write A* (according to wikipedia) and i want to retrieve the path through backtracking, however this is what i end up with.(i found a similar question but the algorithm there wasnt taking priority based on f-cost)

So for a bit of context:
i have an adjacency matrix which specifies which nodes are connected and which are not, and tried writing A* based on this.

```
    HashSet<Vector3f> openSet = new HashSet();
    LinkedHashMap<Vector3f,Vector3f> cameFrom = new LinkedHashMap();// 1 - node / 2 - nodes parent
    HashMap<Vector3f,Float> gScore = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Vector3f,Float> fScore = new HashMap();
    
    gScore.put(actor.getStartingNode(), 0f);
    fScore.put(actor.getStartingNode(), (abs(actor.getStartingNode().x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(actor.getStartingNode().z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));
    openSet.add(actor.getStartingNode());

    while(!actor.getFoundPath() && !openSet.isEmpty() && !actor.hasLineOfSight){ // pathfinding loop
    float lowestF =  Collections.min(fScore.values());
    Vector3f currentNode = null;

    for(Object entry: fScore.entrySet()) {  // get lowest Fcost node 
    Entry<Vector3f,Float>entry1 = (Entry) entry;
      if(entry1.getValue().equals(lowestF)) {
        currentNode = entry1.getKey();
        break;
      }
    } // get lowest Fcost node 

    if(currentNode.equals(actor.getEndingNodePos())){ // found path- quit and backtrack the path
    actor.setFoundPath(true);
    reconstructPath(cameFrom,currentNode); // doesnt work

    break;
    }
    
    openSet.remove(currentNode);
    
    
    for(Object adjacentToCurrent : adjacencyMatrix.get(currentNode)){ // nodes adjacent to currentNode
    Vector3f neighbor = (Vector3f) adjacentToCurrent;
    float tentativeScore = gScore.get(currentNode)+(abs(currentNode.x-neighbor.x)+abs(currentNode.z-neighbor.z));
    if(!gScore.containsKey(neighbor)){
    gScore.put(neighbor, 1000000f);  // setting the value as 1000000f as a replacement for infinity
    }
    
    if(tentativeScore<gScore.get(neighbor)){
    cameFrom.replace(neighbor, currentNode);
    gScore.replace(neighbor, tentativeScore);
    fScore.replace(neighbor,tentativeScore+(abs(neighbor.x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(neighbor.z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));
    if(!openSet.contains(neighbor)){
        cameFrom.putIfAbsent(neighbor, currentNode);
    gScore.putIfAbsent(neighbor, tentativeScore);
        fScore.putIfAbsent(neighbor,tentativeScore+(abs(neighbor.x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(neighbor.z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));
    openSet.add(neighbor);
    }
    }
        
        
    }
 fScore.remove(currentNode);
        gScore.remove(currentNode);

    }
   

    }
```

the path should be stored in **cameFrom** (made it LinkedHashMap so it maintains order), however, this is what the graphical representation of my **cameFrom** looks like:[cameFrom.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q6vg.jpg)

Which of course means the path ultimately was found, but its not the shortest possible. Could anyone tell me where i got the path "writing" wrong? (the algorithm is basically 1:1 from wikipedia, however i had to change some things because it was written in pseudocode)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a lot of energy to read the code or think about the solution.  But I would use a stack.  Each node I visit, I would push it onto the stack.  Each time, I back track, I would pop the stack.  When you reach the destination, pop all the nodes and store them in a list.  This is the path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The stack will simplify the code, however i managed to make it work without it.

Answer (score 0):

here's the working version:
The a* algorithm

```
  public static void aStarSearch(GameObject actor){
    HashSet<Vector3f> openSet = new HashSet();
    HashSet<Vector3f> closedSet = new HashSet();
    LinkedHashMap<Vector3f,Vector3f> cameFrom = new LinkedHashMap();// 1 - node / 2 - nodes parent
    HashMap<Vector3f,Float> gScore = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Vector3f,Float> fScore = new HashMap();
    

    gScore.put(actor.getStartingNode(), 0f);
    fScore.put(actor.getStartingNode(), (abs(actor.getStartingNode().x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(actor.getStartingNode().z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));
    openSet.add(actor.getStartingNode());
//    long sum = 0;
//   System.out.println("ending node " + actor.getEndingNodePos());
    while(!actor.getFoundPath() && !openSet.isEmpty() && !actor.hasLineOfSight){ // # 4 a) b)
    float lowestF =  Collections.min(fScore.values());
    Vector3f currentNode = null;

//    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(Object entry: fScore.entrySet()) {
    Entry<Vector3f,Float>entry1 = (Entry) entry;
      if(entry1.getValue().equals(lowestF)) {
        currentNode = entry1.getKey();
        break;
      }
    }
//    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis()-time1;
//    sum += time2;

    
    if(currentNode.equals(actor.getEndingNodePos())){
    actor.setFoundPath(true);
    reconstructPath(cameFrom,currentNode);

    break;
    }
    
    openSet.remove(currentNode);
    closedSet.add(currentNode);
    
    for(Object adjacentToCurrent : adjacencyMatrix.get(currentNode)){
    Vector3f neighbor = (Vector3f) adjacentToCurrent;
    if(!closedSet.contains(neighbor)){
    float tentativeScore = gScore.get(currentNode)+(abs(currentNode.x-neighbor.x)+abs(currentNode.z-neighbor.z));
   boolean tentativeScoreIsBetter = false;
   
   
   if(!openSet.contains(neighbor)){    
//    cameFrom.putIfAbsent(neighbor, currentNode);
//    gScore.putIfAbsent(neighbor, tentativeScore);
//    fScore.putIfAbsent(neighbor,tentativeScore+(abs(neighbor.x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(neighbor.z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));
    openSet.add(neighbor);
    tentativeScoreIsBetter = true;
//    System.out.println("dodaje");
    } else if(tentativeScore<gScore.get(neighbor)){
    tentativeScoreIsBetter = true;
    }
   if(tentativeScoreIsBetter){
   if(cameFrom.keySet().contains(neighbor)){
   cameFrom.replace(neighbor, currentNode);
       gScore.replace(neighbor, tentativeScore);
    fScore.replace(neighbor,tentativeScore+(abs(neighbor.x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(neighbor.z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));

   }else{
   cameFrom.put(neighbor,currentNode);
    gScore.put(neighbor, tentativeScore);
    fScore.put(neighbor,tentativeScore+(abs(neighbor.x-actor.getEndingNodePos().x)+abs(neighbor.z-actor.getEndingNodePos().z)));

   }
   }
   
    }
    }
 fScore.remove(currentNode);
        gScore.remove(currentNode);

    }
   

    }
```

reconstructing the path

```
   public static void reconstructPath(HashMap cameFrom,Vector3f currentNode){
        
        LinkedList<Vector3f>finalPath = new LinkedList();

      while(cameFrom.keySet().contains(currentNode)){
      currentNode = (Vector3f)cameFrom.get(currentNode);
      finalPath.addFirst(currentNode);
      }

    
    }
```

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer